# lm-sensors not showing voltages

Tags: 16.04, lm-sensors

I've done as suggested here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto and run `sudo sensors-detect` and entered `yes` for everything.

Still I only get this:

```
:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +31.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +34.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

System Information

```
  PROCESSOR:          Intel Core i7-4790K @ 4.40GHz (8 Cores)
    Core Count:       4
    Thread Count:     8
    Extensions:       SSE 4.2 + AVX2 + AVX + RDRAND + FSGSBASE
    Cache Size:       8192 KB
    Microcode:        0x1e
    Scaling Driver:   intel_pstate powersave

  GRAPHICS:           Intel HD 4600 (1250MHz)
    Display Driver:   intel 2.99.917
    Monitor:          S27C750
    Screen:           1920x1080

  MOTHERBOARD:        ASUS Z97I-PLUS
    Memory:           16384MB
    Chipset:          Intel 4th Gen Core DRAM
    Network:          Intel Connection + Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless

  DISK:               240GB Kingston SHPM228
    File-System:      ext4
    Mount Options:    data=ordered errors=remount-ro relatime rw
    Disk Scheduler:   DEADLINE

  OPERATING SYSTEM:   Ubuntu 16.04
    Kernel:           4.4.0-78-generic (x86_64)
    Desktop:          GNOME Shell 3.18.5
    Compiler:         GCC 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: If your Motherboard is not equipped with voltage sensor, it won't be displayed.

Comment: Voltages show up in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that this board is equipped with Nuvoton NCT6791D chip (or similar). I couldn't find that information via Google, and chances are high it is not available anywhere unless someone has physically looked at the board and checked if the chip is there. The manual might, but usually doesn't, contain this information.

Another thing is that many motherboard manufacturers (ASUS being one of them) make an ACPI implementation that conflicts with reading the chips manually (i.e. by software). This can be worked around by kernel parameters, but this can (according to documentation) be dangerous - as in: cause HW malfunction  and / or crashes resulting in data loss. Even HW damage can not be ruled out! Seems that the most accurate information about this is in the lm-sensors FAQ, which is not online at the moment, and in Kernel development bugzilla. [Here is a link to the former in WayBack Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150823051215/http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter3#Mysensorshavestoppedworkinginkernel2.6.31).

**DISCLAIMER:** The discussion is so technical that I do not understand it nor the potential risks involved in using the parameter below. **The problem is, as far as I understand it, that some obscure bugs / situations might arise since two separate pieces of code are using the same registers, which might lead into, among other things, CPU voltages set to unsafe levels.**

If you want to try it despite the above warnings, you may want to add in Kernel parameters:

```
 "acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

And then either:

1. load nct6775 module (more safe, possibly)
2. re-run sensors detect (not that safe).

In case 1. we are guessing your motherboard has a chip supported by the module. If it is not, there is really no other option than 2., save for giving up on reading sensor data.

**TL;DR:** Read the above explanation, links and bug reports - and try this at your own risk!.